# JSON not decoding properly

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap as the base framework for my web application.

I'm trying to use JSON to pass data back from my PHP script to the client, using this piece of javascript:

```
$(function($) {
    $('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data, status) {
                $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $target.html(response.html)
                });
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

However, what is being written to the model is JSON data and not the HTML I'm expecting.

Server-side code:

```
$ContentBits['content'] = $this->content;

    $html = ContentFactory::capture_output(ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . 'cbd' . DS . 'templates' . DS . 'ajaxAlert.php');

    $jsonArray = array(
        'html' => $html,
        'resultCode' => 1
    );
    $json = json_encode($jsonArray);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json;
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting? I mean the value of `response` and Check for `$target`. Try replacing `url` in the `$.getJSON` with `$form.attr('action')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.getJSON` method already parses the result from the server as JSON, so you don't need to call `$.parseJSON` once again. The `data` parameter that is passed to your callback will already represent a JSON object that you could use directly:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $target.html(data.html);
});
```

Comment: That's probably because inside the `html` property you still have JSON. Check and fix your server side code so that you store HTML inside this property.

Comment: I've added the PHP script I'm using to generate the JSON, no JSON is present until the end.

Comment: In the server side script you have shown you seem to be using some `ContentFactory::capture_output` function which I have strictly no idea what is doing nor what it returns. So what does this function return? Make sure it is HTML if you want this to work.

Comment: All that function is, is output buffering wrapped in a function. Raw HTML is returned, as string. Should I be base64_encoding and decoding the HTML?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question: what does this function return? Can you provide some sample output from it? If it's raw HTML as string then this should work. You don't need any base64 encoding. For example instead of using this function simply hardcode some sample html: `$html = '<div>Hello</div>';` and see if this works. If this works then you have a problem with this function. If it doesn't work then we shall see.

Comment: `{"html":"
Hello<\/div>","resultCode":1}` is what is showing in my modal.

Comment: Alright, could you put the following in your success callback: `console.log(data);` and paste here what is shown in the console?

Comment: And what about `console.log(data.html);`? What does it print?

Comment: Nothing is written to the log

Comment: Now that's strange. It seems that jQuery hasn't parsed JSON the output from the server even though it should have because you have specified the correct Content-Type header in your script.

Comment: Then `console.log(data.html)` should correctly output the value of the HTML.

Comment: I wasn't using Firebug for debugging - on Chrome at the moment.

Comment: That doesn't really matter.

Comment: Edit, actually, Chrome can't see `console.log(data);` either